# AJAX URL Navigation 404 Not Found

Tags: php, html, ajax, jquery

So I'm trying to implement an ajax based password change so that the page doesn't refresh when the user hits submit. So here's my html, jquery, and php:

```
Current Password<input type="password" id="change_password" name="change_password"><br>
New Password<input type="password" id="new_password" name="new_password"><br>
Verify Password<input type="password" id="verify_password" name="verify_password"><br>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#change_Pass').submit(function(e){
    var $this = $(this);  
    $.ajax({
        data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
        type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
        url: '/Private/change_password.php', // the file to call
        success: function(response) { // on success..
            //$('#success_div).html(response); // update the DIV
            alert("good");
        },
        error: function(e, x, r) { // on error..
            //$('#error_div).html(e); // update the DIV
            alert("bad");
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    return false; //so it doesn't refresh or submit the page
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../classes/Bcrypt.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$usr = $_SESSION["username"];
$old_pwd = $_POST["change_password"];
$new_pwd = $_POST["new_password"];
$new_pwd = Bcrypt::hash($new_pwd);
try {
    $link = new PDO('mysql:host=*;dbname=*;charset=UTF-8','*','*');
    $query = "SELECT *
            FROM Conference
            WHERE Username = :un";

    $stmt = $link->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bindParam(':un', $usr);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetchAll();

    $hash = $row[0]["Password"];
    $is_correct = Bcrypt::check($old_pwd, $hash);

    if($is_correct) {
        $query = "UPDATE Conference
                SET `Password`=:new_pwd 
                WHERE Username = :usr";

        $stmt = $link->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':new_pwd', $new_pwd);
        $stmt->bindParam(':usr', $usr);
        $stmt->execute();
    } 
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

My file structure is just:

```
Folder
    |--Front.php
    |--Private
        |--change_password.php
```

But everytime I enter in the stuff and hit submit. It tries to go to `www.domain.com/Folder/change_password.php` rather than `www.domain.com/Folder/Private/change_password.php`. It just says

```
The requested URL /Folder/change_password.php was not found on this server.
```

I've tried full urls, and just `/Private/change_password.php` and nothing works. I don't understand why it can't see the folder. Any ideas?

Comment: sounds like there is a script error being thrown before the submit handler fires and form is being submitted by browser default method. WHat is the form `action` url? Use a console to look at errors

Comment: @charlietfl wow this was the problem. I had `action="change_password.php"`. Should have been `action="Private/change_password.php"`. Stupid mistake, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
        type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
        url: '/', // the file to call
        success: function(response) { // on success..
            //$(
```

Your Url field is empty

Comment: no i don't know how I copied that over without the url but it's not empty. Editted post.

Answer (score 0):

Use $this and not $(this) and try again:

```
$('#change_Pass').submit(function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        data: $this.serialize(), // $this
        type: $this.attr('method'), // $this
        url: '/Private/change_password.php', //
        success: function(response) {
            alert("good");
        },
        error: function(e, x, r) {
            alert("bad");
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    return false; //so it doesn't refresh or submit the page
});
```